# Does inverse inequality on spatial domain at least for smooth domain exist?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, sobolev-spaces

Does inverse inequality

$\|\nabla u\|_{L^{2}(\Omega)} \leq c_{inv}h^{-1} \|u\|_{L^{2}(\Omega)}$

on the spatial domain, $\Omega$ at least for a smooth domain exist?

Answer (score 1):

No. This cannot work. Think of $\Omega=(0,1)$ and $u_n(x):=\sin(n\pi x)$.

Comment: Thanks for this example.